# Bootstrap row-fluid not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap theme..

I want to make clear : both using row-fluid... in my case...html is ..

```
<div class="flexslider row-fluid" style="max-width:65%;">

                    <ul class="slides">
                        <!--<li>            
                            <img src="images/slide-1.jpg">
                        </li>
                        <li>            
                            <img src="images/slide-2.jpg">
                        </li>-->
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/slide-3.jpg">
                        </li>
                        <!--<li>
                            <img src="images/slide-4.jpg">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/slide-5.jpg">
                        </li>-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="register-box">
                    <div class="reg-title">Join and communicate for FREE!</div>
                    <div class="reg-form">
                        <input type="text" value="Username">
                        <input type="password" value="Password">
                        <input type="password" value="Confirm Password">
                        <input type="checkbox">I agree to the terms and conditions.
                    </div>
                    <div class="signup-button-area">
                        <button>Sign up for free</button></div>
                </div>
```

I want to register-box (Register section) , register section will be fall down after jquery slider section..

Comment: Please upload your relevant code to http://www.jsfiddle.net so it'll be easier to help you

Comment: Try removing the `row-fluid` class since it seems you're not using it properly, rows are only designed to work with children with `span` classes.

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap 3.0.0 ? or Bootstrap 2.3.2 ?

row-fluid only works in Bootstrap 2.3.2, in Bootstrap 3.0.0 you should use row.

Read the changelog [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) if you are using Bootstrap 3.0.0.

If you are using Bootstrap 2.3.2, you can try to add a row-fluid class div to

```
<div class="register-box">
    ....
</div>
<div class="signup-button-area">
    ....
</div>
```

to become

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="register-box">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="signup-button-area">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```